# How to Reverse Geocode?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding

I am pretty new to ArcMap, only learning this program within the last few days.

I have this parcel data in a .shp file, as well as a proposed highway. I need to find the addresses of each parcel and export them into a database, excel file, etc.[image: Parcel + Proposed Highway].

I know I can use the Geocode tool and find the address by holding the left-click button, but I am not sure how to extract the information.

Comment: Make your parcels points and then use http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//002600000009000000.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to geocode for this.
You could try using the [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00080000000q000000) tool (join the parcels to the proposed highway), or even the [Select by Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) too.

Open the attribute table when the parcels are highlighted, under Table Options in the top left click Export and you can export the table. You can export as a File and Personal Geodatabase table, a dBase table and text file.

Comment: I have done this exact thing. I open the attribute table up, I get all the information I need except the address. Attached a link here to show what I am talking about.    http://postimg.org/image/pq09cexdt/

Comment: Try Mapperz suggestion if there is no address information in the attribute table.